# Draft js codeblock text overflow

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am having a hard time trying to prevent the overflowing text inside a codeblock. The problem seem to be only with codeblocks, which ignores its parent container width.
As per the example below, when editing using a codeblock the text is not breaking into new lines when reaching the end of the container.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1oqr4xyy6j

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/r4qx32m8wm

I made this change in `rich-editor.css`

CSS

```
.RichEditor-editor .public-DraftStyleDefault-pre pre {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your CSS:

```
pre {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/64w873v2mn).

Comment: Tried that as a workaround, but doesn't seem to be the expected behavior as shown here https://draftjs.org/